# AutoComplete with KnockoutJs

Tags: knockout.js

i developed a page with couple of text boxes which are auto completed
with some source and selectable button.on button click it looks for
the options selected in textbox. if the user selects option from list
it was working as it should be but if the user clears the text box and
cliked on button it still has the previous selected values of text
boxes.

i am thinking like clicking of button after clearing out text boxes
didn't loose focus of text box.hence the empty string is not attached
to selected value. but if click the button again this time it worked
as programmed.

my application is similar to   http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/MJQ6g/

any help on this should be appreciated.

Comment: Can you put a jsfiddle so we can see what is happeaning?

Comment: my code very similar to http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/MJQ6g/ except few more text boxes on clearing data it's not focusing out of the box hence prev selected value still persists in observable

Answer (score 0):

Bind your textbox to a KO observable. Call .subscribe on that observable. Inside that .subscribe handler, check if the value is set to an empty string. If it is, clear the value stored in the selected value observable.